# How can I break when found QR Code in Python?

Tags: python, qr-code

I'm trying to learning QR Code module in Python and I'm trying to make some codes so I want to break when I found QR Code how can I do that?

**My code is:**

```
while 1:

    success, img= cap.read()
    for x in decode(img):
        data1 = x.data.decode('utf-8')
        pts = np.array([x.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(122,25,245),(3))
        print(data1)
        
    cv2.imshow('Result',img)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Comment: The break keyword is your friend here. Place it at the end of the if statement

Comment: @ScienceSnake sorry but how can I do that I don't know, can you explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement in the range loop, if there is something there, print that it has been detected

```
   while 1:
    
        success, img= cap.read()
        for x in decode(img):
            data1 = x.data.decode('utf-8')
            pts = np.array([x.polygon],np.int32)
            pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
            cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(122,25,245),(3))
            print(data1)
            if data1 is not None:
                print("QR code detected")
                break

     cv2.imshow('Result',img)
     cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Comment: hm, that's very strange, it should stop the loop. have you tried removing things? like removing "print(data1)". or is everything in line? break should work in stopping it